# to show the name of the department which has maximum student count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

There are two tables in total, one is "Department" which has department_name, department_block_number and department_id(primary key) in it and another is "Student" which has student_name,student_id and department_id(foreign key) in it. So based on this scenario, we have to show the name of the department which has maximum student count.

I have tried out something, below you can find my code but it didn't work as expected, so can you help me in rectifying it?

```
select u 
from 
    (select count(s.student_id) cnt,d.department_name u 
    from department d 
    join student s using(department_id) 
    group by d.department_name 
    where cnt==(select max(cntt) from (select
        count(ss.student_id) cntt,dd.department_name 
        from department dd 
        join student ss using(department_id) 
        group by dd.department_name)
    )
);
```

Note: This problem belongs to SubQueries section.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to get a count of all students in all departments in descending order, then limit to the first result:

```
SELECT a.`department_name`
    count(b.`student_id`) as `num_students`
FROM `Department` a
JOIN `Student` b
ON a.`department_id` = b.`department_id`
GROUP BY `a.department_id`
ORDER BY count(b.`student_id`) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, I should tell you that I found this problem in SubQueries section. Also, initially I tried "Select TOP 1....." ,this "Limit 1" and all, but the code didn't get accepted. So no matter what, unless we used SubQueries, it would not get accepted. That constraint is there.

Comment: "I should tell you that I found this problem in SubQueries section"? Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Please review the help section for info on how to ask a question, and the types of questions that are appropriate on SO.

Comment: Sorry, Had i asked something wrong. I tried as much as I could. and You could also see what I tried, above. Yet, I could not make it. Can you help me with it?

Comment: You might try to setup a SQL Fiddle, or edit your question and provide the table schemas and some (small amount) sample data.